# UpdatePanel controls unavailable - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel with a Label control, Label1, and a button outside it, Button1, and another Label control outside the UpdatePanel, Label2.  When the button is clicked, I want the Label text to be updated in Label1:

**ASPX page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" AsyncPostBackTimeout="0" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <asp:ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </asp:ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "some text";
    Label1.Text = "some text";
}
```

This should be straight-forward - I should be able to update the Label1 text with a button click event.  The Label2 line succeeds (it obviously won't appear without a page postback, though), where the Label1 line fails with "Object reference is not an instance of an object".  Why is Label1 null, when it is right there on the page, just that it is inside an UpdatePanel?  How am I supposed to instantiate controls that should already be on the page and accessible, just like Label2 is?

Comment: The closing tag of `Label1` is incorrect. Is it just a typo? (The same for `Label2` by the way)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yeah, corrected.  Had to type everything in here manually from another computer.

Comment: Can you remove `AsyncPostBackTimeout="0"`?

Comment: Tried that, and removing `EnablePartialRendering="true"` to give a "pure vanilla" ScriptManager and no dice.

Comment: I copied and tested your code in an empty project and it works perfectly. You may try the same, if that is not what you already have. Anything else on the page? Can you show the page directive line?

Comment: Yeah - just edited the copy above to what I really had... I was stupid... had `<asp:ContentTemplate>` instead of `<ContentTemplate>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code has `<asp:ContentTemplate>` and `</asp:ContentTemplate>` instead of `<ContentTemplate>` and `</ContentTemplate>` tags in the UpdatePanel.  I corrected this and it works now.  The controls became out of scope since the code couldn't find the real ContentTemplate or anything in it.

Comment: And now this answer has the opposite problem. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Caught me, again!  Corrected.  Long day!  Thanks.

Comment: You can accept your own answer, especially since the other answer is getting up votes even though it is incorrect (sorry amoyer).

Comment: Yeah, it says I have to wait 2 days, though. And actually yeah - now that I have it working, if I put my Button inside the panel, it stops working.

Comment: If you put the button inside the panel, you can remove the triggers list. The option `ChildrenAsTriggers` is `true` by default.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes! Awesome! Thanks!  Actually, I found after I corrected the `<ContentTemplate>` tags, it works regardless of where the button is and if the `<Triggers>` section is there or not.

Comment: If the button is outside of the UpdatePanel and not included in the triggers, it will cause a full postback, however. So, it will appear to work but not exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your async trigger must be *inside* the update panel. It may not be finding it because it is not inside of the update panel. Furthermore, because you are doing an async postback, only what is inisde of the update panel will get refreshed; thus you are in essence "reseting" Label 1.

This is why your code behind cannot find Label 1. Do this:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

This will help you to see. The labels 1 and 3 will always get updated now, but since label 2 is outside of the update panel, it will not because the Page doesn't see this on postback.

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Label3.Text = "label 3";
      Label2.Text = "label 2";
      Label1.Text = "label 1";
 }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: When I put the button in the panel's ContentTemplate it gives me an error: `A control with ID 'Button1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'`.

Comment: The button can be outside of the UpdatePanel. If it is included in the triggers list, it should trigger the async postback.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, I believe that to be true.  Especially since adding it to the UpdatePanel seems to make it "invisible", just like my Label control, to my code.